# Docker compose networking - Priority property ignored

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I composed docker-compose.yaml file which contains 4 network interfaces, these interfaces needs to be in a specific order when mounted to the docker container.

Docker Engine Version: 19.03

Docker-compose Version: 2.4.1

we're using `macvlan` driver as part of our system in order to have L2 packets transfer between host interfaces.
and the docker container we're using to host everything on is based on ubuntu:18.04

```yaml
networks:
    sim1:
       name: sim1
       driver: macvlan
       driver_opts:
           parent: ens20
           macvlan_mode: bridge
       ipam:
           config:
           - subnet: 192.3.0.0/16
             ip_range: 192.3.1.0/24
    sim2:
       name: sim2
       driver: macvlan
       driver_opts:
           parent: ens21
           macvlan_mode: bridge
       ipam:
           config:
           - subnet: 192.4.0.0/16
             ip_range: 192.4.1.0/24
    sim3:
       name: sim1
       driver: macvlan
       driver_opts:
           parent: ens20
           macvlan_mode: bridge
       ipam:
           config:
           - subnet: 192.5.0.0/16
             ip_range: 192.5.1.0/24
    sim4:
       name: sim1
       driver: macvlan
       driver_opts:
           parent: ens20
           macvlan_mode: bridge
       ipam:
           config:
           - subnet: 192.6.0.0/16
             ip_range: 192.6.1.0/24
```

I saw that there's a property called: `priority`, this property allows to organize the network interfaces according to a metrics you specify on the compose.yaml file.

> priority indicates in which order Compose implementation SHOULD connect the service’s containers to its networks. If unspecified, the default value is 0.

[Docker-compose priority](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#priority)

When trying to apply this priority feature on the yaml file I'm getting no errors and no warnings, just ignored on the docker side, and when executing ifconfig I see that the interfaces got in a wrong order.

This is the output of the ifconfig (after filter the results)

```
eth0: sim1
eth1: sim4
eth2: sim3
eth3: sim2
```

```yaml
services:
   app1:
       image: nginx:latest
       command: "tail -f /dev/null"
       networks:
          sim1:
              priority: 1000
          sim2:
              priority: 900
          sim3:
              priority: 800
          sim4:
              priority: 700
```

I've been searched the internet without any luck and saw that there's a lot of peoples who came across this without any luck.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4645)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The networks should be connected in alphabetical order. You can see a demonstration of this behavior in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jfellus/cfee9efc1e8e1baf9d15314f16a46eca). I think the problem is in your compose file. Under the `networks:` section you have:

```
sim3:
  name: sim1
```

and

```
sim4:
  name: sim1
```

Notice how both `sim3` and `sim4` have their name set as `sim1`.

If you make these all unique in the correct order and get rid of the priority settings then it should work as expected.

```
services:
  app1:
    image: nginx:latest
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
    networks:
      - sim1
      - sim2
      - sim3
      - sim4

networks:
  sim1:
    name: sim1
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ens20
      macvlan_mode: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.3.0.0/16
        ip_range: 192.3.1.0/24
  sim2:
    name: sim2
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ens21
      macvlan_mode: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.4.0.0/16
        ip_range: 192.4.1.0/24
  sim3:
    name: sim3
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ens20
      macvlan_mode: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.5.0.0/16
        ip_range: 192.5.1.0/24
  sim4:
    name: sim4
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ens20
      macvlan_mode: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.6.0.0/16
        ip_range: 192.6.1.0/24
```

Comment: The problem you mentioned its a typo, it was suppose to be ```sim1: sim1 sim2: sim2  ``` and so on and so on. About the alphabetical you are right, but is there a way to make it to work with priority?

Comment: Network priority is in the spec for docker compose v3 but not working in v2. They have an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8561) to track this feature. You will be able to use it eventually but until then, the alphabetical workaround is the only way.